# What am I doing wrong with my .bat that deletes a folder?

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I have a folder named "Red" and in it is a jpeg. I want to delete this folder, and the picture inside, but I don't want it to ask me if i want to delete it, I just want the program to delete it and move on.

It's located on my desktop.

Here is the code I have to delete the folder and picture

```
del /Q "C:\Users\Chris\Desktop\Red"
```

When I run the .bat it doesn't do anything, it just opens the CMD and closes. Is there a problem with the syntax? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `del` command is not the right tool for deleting a *folder* and its contents. Rather you should use `rmdir` (or `rd`) instead, with the option to delete subfolders/files (and without prompting):

```
rmdir /s /q whatever
```

The `del` command *will* work quietly without prompting and it *will* descend through directory structures but it will only delete *files* in those structures. If you set up the following hierarchy:

```
xyzzy
|
+----- xyzzy.txt
|
+----- plugh
       |
       +----- plugh.txt
       |
       +----- twisty
              |
              +----- twisty.txt
```

and then run `del /s /q xyzzy`, all you will see is:

```
Deleted file - C:\Users\Pax\Documents\xyzzy\xyzzy.txt
Deleted file - C:\Users\Pax\Documents\xyzzy\plugh\plugh.txt
Deleted file - C:\Users\Pax\Documents\xyzzy\plugh\twisty\twisty.txt
```

and you'll be left with the tree untouched (but all the files gone):

```
xyzzy
|
+----- plugh
       |
       +----- twisty
```

If instead you use `rmdir /s /q xyzzy`, the whole tree (including the top level) will be removed.